# How to remove the white space in Jekyll?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

In Jekyll templating, the Liquid tags used can generate a lot of white spaces. From Liquid's documents, use `{{-`  `-}}` or `{{%` `%}}` can strip these white spaces.

But I got a `Liquid syntax error` when Jekyll building.

How to fix this problem or do you have any other methods to remove the white spaces?

Comment: Are your templates in markdown or HTML. I find whitespace in HTML. Not so much in markdown.

Comment: It's a Liquid 4 feature. Jekyll still use Liquid 3.x

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `{{-` and `{%-` tags exist in the latest beta version of Liquid but Jekyll uses the latest stable version, which doesn't include those tags.

When there's a stable release of Liquid 4.0, the next release of Jekyll should include that update and thus those tags will be available to use on Jekyll sites.

Comment: Yes, I wrote that page.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this is specific to Shopify, but you could try using the [strip filter](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/strip/).

**Input**: `{{ "          So much room for activities!          " | strip }}`

**Output**: `So much room for activities!`

Comment: I can confirm this works, even in cases where the accepted answer doesnt

Answer (score 1):

Jekyll v4 support using `{{%- test_function -%}}` and `{{- variable -}}` ([details](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/basics/whitespace/)).

Otherwise [the compression](http://jch.penibelst.de/) extension can be used.

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one Gem that will remove white space post build.

https://github.com/itafroma/jekyll-newline_collapse

https://github.com/stereobooster/html_press

Answer (score 0):

I have had success using the remove method and specifying a blank space:

```
Input
{{ "Multiple words here" | remove: " " }}

Output
Multiplewordshere
```